# Input user to get the dictionary python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a entry widget where I can put the dictionary number, so in this case I have number 1 and 2.

If I put number 1 in the entry widget it will print the number. What I am trying to do is enter a number and get the corresponding key value pair which isn't working. If I type in IDLE info[1] it is working but when I'm trying through the function it isn't working. I get the error KeyError.

```
Interface = Tk()
Interface.title("H")

info = {1: {"url":"https://..."},2: {"url":"https://..."}}


def dictklik():
    p = VulIn.get()
    print(p)
## not working print(info[p])

w = Button(Interface, text="Press", command=dictklik)
w.place(x=80,y =15)



Label(Interface,text="Typ the number").pack()

searchD = IntVar()
VulIn = Entry(Interface, textvariable=searchD)
VulIn.pack()





Interface.geometry("500x500")
Interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you reading the input in as an int or a string?

Comment: @MasonCaiby as an integer

Comment: `VulIn` is the Entry itself - calling `.get()` on that always returns a string.  `searchD.get()` would retrieve the value via your IntVar, which would convert it to an int that is usable as a key in your map.

Comment: @jasonharper so instead of the p = VulIn.get() I need to replace it with searchD.get() ?

Comment: That, or `p = int(VulIn.get())` which has basically the same effect.

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks. It worked for me but I have a question. What is IntVar() doing in this situation then?

Comment: If you use `VulIn.get()`, then the IntVar isn't doing anything.  Tk's Vars tend to not be very useful with Entries - the one exception I can think of is that you can put a write trace on the Var, and be informed of changes to the Entry's contents immediately.  Vars are much more useful with Radiobutton and Checkbutton widgets.